# What is a many to many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, many-to-many, has-many-through

I'm a bit confused on what a many to many relationship is. I'm wondering if the following is a many to many relationship:

A student at a school has many clubs. A club at a school has many students. Let's say that the student has many attributes: firstname, lastname, phone, age, email, etc. A club only has one attribute: a name.

When I make a new club, I want to be able to give the club a name and one or more students. Upon making the club, I want that club to be associated with those students and those students to be associated with that club.

When I make a new student, I want to be able to give the student a firstname, last name, etc, and one or more clubs. Upon making the student, I want that student to be associated with those clubs and those clubs to be associated with that student.

I also want to display a club's students and a student's clubs on their show pages.

I've read that a many to many relationship is when you have a join table that lets you access common attributes of the resulting students and clubs, but there are no common attributes in my case.

Do I have a many to many relationship here? If so, do I use a HABTM or has_many, through relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually yes you DO have common attributes.

You stated yourself that a Student has many Clubs
And a Club has many Students.

What is in common?  Students and Clubs.

What now follows is to define what a Student and a Club actually are, which you already did.

A Student is a combination of firstname, last name, etc...   What you have not specified is what makes a Student UNIQUE.  A club also must be defined as to what will make it UNIQUE.  While for academic purposes, you could say the name is what makes it unique, in real live, that would probably not be the best solution.

Usually for performance purposes, each student is given a unique Autoincrement ID (which is a number).
Same thing can be done with the Club.

You create a 3rd table which is what creates the Many to Many relation.

In that 3rd table, you have 2 columns.  One with the Unique Index for the Student, and the other column with the Unique Index for the Club.   You simply add an entry on that table in which you wish to relate a student to a club.

Since you can have many students assigned to the same club, and you can have many clubs assigned to the same student, you have a many to many relation.

Edit: As mentioned in another answer, your 3rd table should also declare the combined indexes as unique, so that you don't add the same entry multiple times.

Comment: Wow, thanks! This makes a lot more sense. I'm now confused on how make a new student/club, what do I do with the 3rd table? Previously using and one to many relationship on both sides, I used each student and club's ids as strong parameters and saved them in a form. But with the 3rd table now, I'm not sure what to do here...

Comment: Well, the whole idea is that you wish to be able to add multiple students to multiple clubs.  So, usually you will have a Form for creating the club, a Form to create the student, and a Form to tie the student to the club.  That said, once you have that worked out, you can get clever in creating an interface to tie things in a nicer way.

Comment: The form to tie them together can be a list of Students, and a list of clubs, select one from each and click the button to "Join" them by inserting the value to the 3rd table.   If you have ever created a Playlist on an iPOD device, that is basically what you are doing.  You start with selecting the Playlist, and then start selecting the songs you wish to relate to the playlist.  A simple example of Many to Many, where the song can be in multiple playlist, and a playlist can have multiple songs.

Comment: So you're saying that I shouldn't immediately add a club(s) to the student when making a new student on the form but instead have another form that connects the two? EDIT: after reading your new comment, I get it now but is there a way to "mmediately add a club(s) to the student when making a new student on the form"

Comment: Exactly.  Once you have that, then you could get clever and improve it in a way that it flows nicer... (using Ajax for example) but that is the basic way to get it working.

Comment: Yes!  But before you add a new Club, you would check to see if that club already exists.  If it does exist, get the ID, skip the Club insert, and then call the insert to the 3rd table, all part of the same form call.   You can do the same with the Student (check if he exist).   But be warned, people usually make typos, so you might end up with the same club/student entered multiple times with slightly miss-typed names.

Answer (score 2):

You have a many to many

Create an id for each table that is unique for that table typically an auto incrementing int.

Then a third table that is a junction/intersect table call it X.

Put a row in X with the student id and club id if the student has the club and vice versa. It would have a unique composite key in table X across both id's in it.

The composite would guarantee no duplicate rows in X

Comment: Thanks! Now, I'm having trouble what to do with the 3rd table when I make a new student or club in the controllers/views. Can you explain this roughly or it'd be great if there were some online resources for what the controller/views look like with a has many through or HABTM relationship?

Comment: Remember that a student and club can intersect 0 or 1 times and no more. If Johnny quits the club or the club kicks him out, you delete the intersect row. So you need to design a GUI to do this

Comment: I am sure you have seen GUIs like this on your OS. Call them a users screen (you add tbe Shares they are in or delete). You see the Shares screen (you add the users given permission or delete that permission)

Comment: You dont add a student to a group on student creation (not that you couldn't). And vice versa

Comment: Thanks very much! I was too focused on doing that, but its clearer now that I should link them separately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed there is a many-to-many relationship here, use HABTM. Also, why do you say that there are no attributes in common? Club names and student names are definitely common attributes in this case.